# What's wrong with my code ? If else statement for 10 button 10 activity

Tags: android

What's wrong with my code? If else statement for 10 button 10 activity. I uploaded the picture of my code.?
What's wrong with my code? If else statement for 10 button 10 activity. I uploaded the picture of my code.?

```
    public void showGreeting (View view) {
    String button_text;
    button_text = ((Button) view).getText().toString();
    if (button_text.equals("Chapter 2 and 6")) {

    } else (button_text.equals("Chapter 7 Part 1"))
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecindActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    else (button_text.equals("Chapter 7 Part 2"))
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ThirdActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    else (button_text.equals("Chapter 8 and Chapter 9 Part 1"))
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, FourthActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    else (button_text.equals("Chapter 9 Part 2"))
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, FifthActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    else (button_text.equals("Chapter 10"))
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SixthActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    else (button_text.equals("Chapter 11 Part 1"))

    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SeventhActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    else (button_text.equals("Chapter 11 Part 2 and Chapter 12 Part 1"))
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, EighthActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    else (button_text.equals("Chapter 12 Part 2"))
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NinthActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else if (button_text.equals("Credit")) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TenthActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not post code as images. It's text, post it as such.

Comment: instead of using if else statement you can go with switch statement.also for matching button click you are comparing button text instead of it you can use the id of a button.

Comment: your code is not efficient, why you not only make 1 target activity, and pass the title, so if it load the content, you can just use the title to sql

Comment: can you please write the code ? @keronconk

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private Button button1;
//create the 10 buttons here

public void showGreetings(Button button) {
    Intent intent;
    switch (button.getId()) {
        case R.id.button:
            intent = new Intent(this, SecindActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            intent = new Intent(this, ThirdActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;

        case R.id.button3:
            intent = new Intent(this, FourthActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.button4:
            intent = new Intent(this, FifthActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.button5:
            intent = new Intent(this, SixthActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.button6:
            intent = new Intent(this, SeventhActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.button7:
            intent = new Intent(this, EighthActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.button8:
            intent = new Intent(this, NinthActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.button9:
            intent = new Intent(this, TenthActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.button10:
            intent = new Intent(this, Eleventh_Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;

    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showGreetings((Button) view);
        }
    });
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showGreetings((Button) view);
        }
    });
    //do the same with the other 9 buttons

}
```

The id obtained in `b.getId()` is the id you give to the button in xml. You can compare this way instead of a lot of else if statements.

Otherwise you can also do the follow to make it easier and more legible.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private Button button1;
private Button button2;
//create the other 8 buttons here

public void showGreetings(Button button) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecindActivity.class);
    switch (button.getId()) {
        case R.id.button:
            intent.putExtra("POSITION", 1);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            intent.putExtra("POSITION", 2);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.button3:
            intent.putExtra("POSITION", 3);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.button4:
            intent.putExtra("POSITION", 4);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.button5:
            intent.putExtra("POSITION", 5);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.button6:
            intent.putExtra("POSITION", 6);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.button7:
            intent.putExtra("POSITION", 7);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.button8:
            intent.putExtra("POSITION", 8);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.button9:
            intent.putExtra("POSITION", 9);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.button10:
            intent.putExtra("POSITION", 10);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;

    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showGreetings((Button) view);
        }
    });
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showGreetings((Button) view);
        }
    });

    //do the same with the other 9 buttons
}
}
```

And you need just one more activity like this:

```
public class SecindActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    int position = (int) getIntent().getExtras().get("POSITION");
    int layout = 0;
    switch (position) {
        case 1:
            layout = R.layout.second_layout;
            break;
        case 2:
            layout = R.layout.third_layout;
            break;
        // and so on to case = 10;

    }
    setContentView(layout);
}
}
```

Comment: here is the link of my application: please download it and please see this .. this is my college project.  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-yhe0mlTwsiN01WLVpjRWtlVTA/view

Comment: Open Android Monitor when you execute your app, and check there where is the error please.

Comment: no error .
but when go to apk file the buttons do not work . button does not open second , third,. ...... activity.

Comment: Please update gradle and buildtools to the last version

Comment: Thanks brother . Its done. Thanks for your kind help. @Jonathan Aste